# Increase each list element in all possible ways

Tags: python, list

I have a list: `test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`

Need to increase each list element in all possible ways using **Python standard library**. It's a puzzle, and I've already done this:

```
test = [elem + 1 for elem in test]

for i in range(len(test)): test[i] += 1

test = map(lambda x : x + 1, test)

test = [sum(elem) for elem in zip(test, [1]*len(test))]
```

Any others ideas?

Comment: Some of those ways you're technically using a feature of python.

Comment: @ultimatebuster I think you mean all of them --- none of those require imports.

Comment: True... though `map`, `sum`, and `zip` are *technically* functions. Though you could argue that it's python language's feature..

Comment: Yes, the first one isn't using any standart functions, but I think it should be in answer.

Comment: Max, did you mean "Standard Library Functions" or "Built-in Functions"? The ones you can `import` are standard library, the ones you don't have to `import` are built-in. In your examples you only used built-in functions.

Comment: "Standard Library" and "Built-in" together. Any possible ways to increase list using them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion, (and you could use `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0`, but that's just crazy talk):

```
def recurseadd(test):
    if test:
        return [test[False] + True] + recurseadd(test[True:])
    else:
        return test
```

Instead of that `+` you could use `[test[0] + 1].extend(recurseadd(test[1:]))`.

You coud use `operator.add` instead of `+`, with `functools.partial` and `itertools.imap` if you wanted:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import add
from itertools import imap

addone = partial(add, 1)

test = list(imap(addone, test))  # don't really use imap if you want a list
```

You could use `itertools`'s `izip` and `repeat`:

```
test = [sum(elem) for elem in izip(test, repeat(1))]
```

Another method with `sum`, inspired by Eren's comment to GWW's answer:

```
test = sum(([x+1] for x in test), [])
```

Yyou could use `xrange` instead of `range`, you could use `itertools.count(1).next()` to generate the `1`s...

There are an infinite number of minor variations, but your three plus the recursive version seem to cover the basic ones. Eren's reduce version is nice too.

Comment: @MaxLobur Wow, never had an answer accepted after nearly this long before :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
In [23]: import operator

In [24]: import itertools

In [25]: list(itertools.starmap(operator.add,zip(test,itertools.repeat(1))))
Out[25]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]

In [26]: list(itertools.imap(operator.add,test,itertools.repeat(1)))
Out[26]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]

In [30]: list(itertools.starmap(operator.add,itertools.izip_longest(test,[],fillvalue=1)))
Out[30]: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
```

Comment: Yay `starmap`! Clever use of `fillvalue` too.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of two using pythons reduce function, however, they are similar to what you have already done.

```
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, l) for l in zip(li, [1]*len(li))]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, (z,1)) for z in li]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for reduce. Didn't know about it. It's a test of standart functions knowing, so any way to do this using them will be helpfull.

Comment: @MaxK - If you're on Python 3 `reduce` has been moved into `functools`.

Comment: `reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y+1],l,[])`

Comment: @Max make sure to look at @Eren's great comment. I added a variation of it to my answer too. `This is so I can ping two people from one comment`